# Using subprocess to call a tshark command

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, tshark

I am trying to read a `.pcapng` in Python using the command:

```
tshark_out = subprocess.getoutput('tshark -r USB.pcapng')
```

However, my code creates an error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)

Can I fix this by doing a conversion in my command or do I need to fix this through changing my Python script?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a legacy Python2 subcommand in Python3 (see [subprocess.getoutput docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getoutput))

Part of the problem is that you're converting a bytes object to a string implicity with getoutput. `0xe2` is 226, which is greater than the range of 128 for [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).
Instead, you should get the stdout and stderr as bytes objects and convert in a later command. For example:

```
# captures the output for 1 packet.
import subprocess as sp
cmd = sp.run(["tshark", "-c", "1"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
print("STDOUT:\n", cmd.stdout, "\n\nSTDERR:\n", cmd.stderr)
```

Gives output

```
STDOUT:
b'    1   0.000000 179.118.244.35.bc.googleusercontent.com \xe2\x86\x92 
192.198.128.5 TLSv1.2  105 Application Data 6c:94:cf:d8:7f:e7 \xe2\x86\x90 
e0:55:3d:71:f7:29\n' 

STDERR:
b"Capturing on 'Wi-Fi: en0'\n1 packets dropped from Wi-Fi: en0\n1 packets captured\n"
```

You now have bytes objects for stdout and stderr. You can decode them with whichever encoding you want (like ASCII, UTF-8) or use them as is in your code.

You may also want to look at [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), which is a python library to manipulate packets.

Note: This example uses run, but there are many [Python Popen wrappers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) that do similar things.